# Append an element to the list if no other element after it is the same as it

Tags: python

```
x = "haaiiillll"
y=list(x)
z=[]
a=len(y)
n=0
for i in y:
    print(y[n:])
    if i != y[n:]:
        z.append(i)
        n+=1
print(z)
```

How do I implement this, I can't understand. I have tried to implement a program where it checks if the value with `i` is there anywhere in the list `y` if not it will add it otherwise it shouldn't.

Comment: So you want to append only if the element is not in the list?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: To confirm it - can you show your expected output in this case? For example, given the sample input, is that expected - `h` only, or others?

Comment: Do you mean list `y` or list `z`

Comment: Is trying to create a list like ' hail', remove the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way of doing it and works well for lists which aren't very huge:

```
x = "haaiiillll"
res = [item for i, item in enumerate(x) if x.find(item, i + 1) == -1]
print(res)
```

output :

```
['h', 'a', 'i', 'l']
```

Using `.find()` we can see if there is any other values equal to `item` from it's position until the end. (second parameter in `find` is the starting point)

Comment: It works, but prob. not very efficient given a long input string?

Comment: @DanielHao you're right, I will mention it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you need to add the element nf the final list only if it appears once in the input list. So,
Change the value of `n` to 1. Keep a set to track whether the element is already seen. And change the condition to check whether the element is in the rest of the list and not seen already.

```
    n=1
    seen = set()
    for i in y:
        if i not in y[n:] and i not in seen:
            z.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
        n+=1
```

You problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if not your_element in your_list:
    your_list.append(your_element)
```

This way, an element will be added to the list only if it isn't in the list.

Comment: It's not working. why should it be your_list because that's the list I am already going through

Answer (score 0):

In the list z there will be only elements different from each other:

```
x = "haaiiillll"
y=list(x)
z=[]
a=len(y)
n=0
for i in y:
    if i not in z:
        z.append(i)
print(z)
```